# tensorflowのsparse_placeholderのAttributeError

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習, tensorflow

tensorflowでスパーステンソルのプレースホルダーに関して以下のように定義しました

```
ph = {
    'adj_norm': tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="adj_mat"),
    'x': tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="x")}
```

しかし，以下のようなエラーが出ます．

> 'adj_norm': tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="adj_mat"),
>   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'sparse_placeholder'

色々調べた結果，tensorflowのバージョンの違いが原因と考えられるのですが，そういう場合はどうすればこのエラーを解決することができますか？
こちらのtensorflowとpythonのバージョンは`tensorflow=2.0.0`,`python=3.6.1`です．

Comment: tf.compat.v1.sparse_placeholder で使えますか？　バージョンアップでapiのパッケージが変わったりするので、リファレンスで調べると該当しそうなものがすぐでてきますよ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow 1のコードをTensorFlow 2で動かしてエラーになっているので、以下のいずれかで解決すると思います。

- TensorFlow 2の文法で書き直す
- TensorFlow 1互換モードで動かす
- TensorFlow 1にダウングレードする

参考）
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

簡単そうなところで、

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

を

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

に変えてみたら、動作しませんかね？